# How to move from DTU to vCore in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

At present we have 3 (Dev, QA & Prod) stages in our azure resources. All the three are using SQL Database 'Standard S6: 400 DTUs'. Because of Dev and QA SQL Database our monthly cost is going more than 700 euro's. I am planning to move from DTU to vCore serverless. Below are my queries,

1. Just going into portal -> Compute and storage -> and changing from DTU to vCore Serverless is the right process?
2. Do i need to take any other things before doing this operation?
3. Does my existing Azure SQL DB is going to get affected by this operation?
4. If things are not fine as per my requirement same way can i come back to DTU mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at this MS doc for details: [Migrate Azure SQL Database from the DTU-based model to the vCore-based model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/migrate-dtu-to-vcore)

1. Just going into portal -> Compute and storage -> and changing from
   DTU to vCore Serverless is the right process?

> Yes! just change to required option from dropdown and click on `Apply`.
> Migrating a database from the DTU-based purchasing model to the
> vCore-based purchasing model is similar to scaling between service
> objectives in the Basic, Standard, and Premium service tiers, with
> similar duration and a minimal downtime at the end of the migration
> process.

2. Do i need to take any other things before doing this operation?

> - Some hardware generations may not be available in every region. Check availability under  [Hardware generations for SQL
>   Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tiers-sql-database-vcore#hardware-generations).
> - In the vCore model, the supported maximum database size may differ depending on hardware generation. For large databases, check supported
>   maximum sizes in the vCore model for  [single
>   databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases)
>   and  [elastic
>   pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-elastic-pools).
> - If you have geo-replicated databases, during migration, you don't have
>   to stop geo-replication, but you must upgrade the secondary database
>   first, and then upgrade the primary. When downgrading, reverse the
>   order **[Also go through the doc once.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/migrate-dtu-to-vcore#:%7E:text=The%20following%20table%20provides%20guidance%20for%20specific%20migration%20scenarios%3A)**

3. Does my existing Azure SQL DB is going to get affected by this
   operation?

> You can copy any database with a DTU-based compute size to a database
> with a vCore-based compute size without restrictions or special
> sequencing as long as the target compute size supports the maximum
> database size of the source database. Database copy creates a
> transactionally consistent snapshot of the data as of a point in time
> after the copy operation starts. It doesn't synchronize data between
> the source and the target after that point in time.

4. If things are not fine as per my requirement same way can i come
   back to DTU mode.

> A database migrated to the vCore-based purchasing model can be
> migrated back to the DTU-based purchasing model at any time in the
> same fashion, with the exception of databases migrated to the
> Hyperscale service tier.

Comment: Thank you @KarthikBhyresh-MT for your replay, will go through the documents.

Comment: My pleasure, do let me know if any queries 

Comment: Hi I read all your comments and found useful. I am not planning to change Prod environment, QA and Dev SQL Database is generating more billing for that reason I am planning to move from DTU mode to vCore server-less mode. So, for these environment I am not using Geo-replication.